# same websites on two domains without getting penalized by google?

Tags: seo, google-search

1. somerandomwebsite.com
2. somerandomwebsite.london

Is it technically possible to host the same entire website on two domains so that google doesn't penalize me?

Comment: Duplicate content rarely causes penalties.  Google usually just chooses to index one of the two domains when they are fully duplicate.   You can use redirects or canonical tags to choose which domain you prefer to have indexed.